# picking rows according to column minimum in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df

```
id      cons_id dist    position
AAA     AAA_1   -20     upstream
AAA     AAA_2   -14     upstream
AAA     AAA_3   -10     upstream
AAA     AAA_4   20      downstream
AAA     AAA_5   25      downstream
AAA     AAA_6   30      downstream
BBB     BBB_1   -30     upstream
BBB     BBB_2   -24     upstream
BBB     BBB_3   -7      upstream
BBB     BBB_4   10      downstream
BBB     BBB_5   35      downstream
BBB     BBB_6   45      downstream
```

I want the output to be such that the row with the largest number to be chosen in the "upstream" class of every "id" and the first row of the "downstream class" (with same "id") having a dist of atleast 40 from the chosen upstream row. Example output :

```
id      cons_id dist    position
AAA     AAA_3   -10     upstream
AAA     AAA_6   30      downstream
BBB     BBB_3   -7      upstream
BBB     BBB_5   35      downstream
```

My attempts at using iterrows to iterate through the dataframe and sort, groupby and finding minimum give errors. Can you suggest a simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by selecting the correct rows of the dataframe first, and then a combination of sorting/grouping.

```
df2 = df[df['dist'] <= 40] # filter out rows greater than 40
df2.sort_values('dist').groupby(['id', 'position']).last().reset_index()
```

The `reset_index()` part will remove the multiindex that the grouping creates.
Also the order of the rows and columns will be a little messed up after this, so you might need to reorder the columns and resort the dataframe.

Comment: I think this is close, but what about the "dist of atleast 40" requirement?